# Which variable cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c, visual-c++, mqtt, paho

Trying to debug unhandled exception in `MQTT Paho` library. Can't figure out in which exact variable rises segmentation fault. Variables m and ma are not NULL. Not sure what does `{...}` means in `m->c->connect_state`.

How to know which exact variable raised the problem?

How to solve this problem?

[image]

Function code in MQTTClient.c:

```
int MQTTClient_setCallbacks(MQTTClient handle, void* context, MQTTClient_connectionLost* cl,
                                                        MQTTClient_messageArrived* ma, MQTTClient_deliveryComplete* dc)
{
    int rc = MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS;
    MQTTClients* m = handle;

    FUNC_ENTRY;
    Thread_lock_mutex(mqttclient_mutex);

    if (m == NULL || ma == NULL || m->c->connect_state != NOT_IN_PROGRESS)
        rc = MQTTCLIENT_FAILURE;
    else
    {
        m->context = context;
        m->cl = cl;
        m->ma = ma;
        m->dc = dc;
    }

    Thread_unlock_mutex(mqttclient_mutex);
    FUNC_EXIT_RC(rc);
    return rc;
}
```

This code is from official Paho library:
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/master/src/MQTTClient.c
And why they make such assignment:
MQTTClients* m = handle;

Comment: Most likely `m->c` is null or invalid, or `m` is not null but pointing somewhere invalid (dangling, uninitialized, etc.)

Comment: Given some `MQTTClient handle` then `MQTTClients* m = handle;` is invalid C. Unless `MQTTClients` (with s) is some exotic type. If this isn't a typo then these are incredibly poor type names.

Comment: Perhaps the debugger shows `{...}` because it doesn't *know* the value due to the error.

Comment: Also what's this macro crap doing `FUNC_ENTRY;`? Get rid of magic mysterious macros so that the code can be read and debugged by C programmers...

Comment: This code is from official Paho library: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/master/src/MQTTClient.c Have no idea about: `MQTTClients* m = handle;`

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the actual text and format it properly. Images are really hard to read, and impossible to search or for people that use screen readers.

Comment: I found this in the Github. `typedef void* MQTTClient;` This seems to be a sloppy library. Anyway, that explains why the cast silently works. But it also means that `MQTTClient_setCallbacks` must be called with a valid `MQTTClients` object passed as first parameter. Otherwise you'll get seg faults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to know which exact variable raised the problem?

Replace

```
if (m == NULL || ma == NULL || m->c->connect_state != NOT_IN_PROGRESS)
    rc = MQTTCLIENT_FAILURE;
```

temporarily with

```
if (m == NULL)
    rc = MQTTCLIENT_FAILURE;

else if (ma == NULL)
    rc = MQTTCLIENT_FAILURE;

else if (m->c->connect_state != NOT_IN_PROGRESS)
    rc = MQTTCLIENT_FAILURE;
```

Now you can see which variable is causing the problems.

Comment: got problem with `m->c->connect_state` since the fact that MQTTClient was not created at all. More details in [Segmentation fault while MQTTClient_setCallbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108837/segmentation-fault-while-mqttclient-setcallbacks)